# Where can I find GIF animations of Facebook Pusheen stickers?

Tags: facebook

I love to use Pusheen stickers in my Facebook messages a lot. Where can I find [GIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format) animations of them?

I'd like to include them in my web page.

Comment: What is pusheen stickers?

Comment: No one ever grab the gif from facebook and share them before. I am going to do it now. I will do it slowly and post a link when I finish.

Comment: And they are actually javascript + png, so they are not GIFs. It will take a long time to manually converting them into GIFs in photoshop.

Comment: Okay here is one of them. http://blog.aerofotea.com/post/137561045015

Comment: It is a lot of work. I suggest we make it a community project and post the finished gif on tumblr with #pusheengif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check this out? I'm not sure about copy rights.

http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/pusheen-gif

Answer (score 1):

Many of Pusheen's Facebook stickers were originally created as animated gifs on Tumblr before being adapted for Facebook.

I spent around an hour searching through posts on the [official Pusheen website](http://www.pusheen.com), compared them against Pusheen's Facebook sticker sets, and embedded any matches I could find below. Each is categorized and links back to their original source. I'll edit my post if I find any more matches.

---

### [Pizza: A how-to](http://www.pusheen.com/post/31227581067)

[image: Pusheen eating pizza]

---

### [Career options for your cat](http://www.pusheen.com/post/27733466731)

[image: Baker]
[image: Pianist]
[image: Blogger]
[image: DJ]

---

### [6 Reasons you should consider being a cat](http://www.pusheen.com/post/21466063041)

[image: Free food]
[image: Free rent]
[image: Sleep as long as you want to]
[image: Look great with no effort]
[image: Toes look like beans]

---

### [Things that I love](http://www.pusheen.com/post/18639509151)

[image: Food]
[image: Sleep]

---

### [New Year's Resolutions](http://www.pusheen.com/post/15098393538)

[image: Expectation]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider building GIF file yourself. After manually getting the Facebook PNG file see [how to find sticker file](http://comexile.blogspot.com.au/2015/07/how-to-save-facebook-stickers-as-gif.html). I think it would be difficult to automate this so you need to get each one to build each GIF. I found some tools that may help make converting the Facebook stickers (= png files) into GIF file these are some Python scripts: [image2gif.py3.py](https://gist.github.com/andy0130tw/d762dfbfae3cdce56cfa) and [sticker-convert.py](https://gist.github.com/andy0130tw/8a5c4ea27808fd28b8e2). I am not a Python coder so I don't know how useful and developed these tool are so far. I hope someone may be interested in building a conversion process out of it, or at least checking out the suitability of the scripts.